# Python and Bluetooth/OBEX

Tags: python, bluetooth

Is there any Python libraries that will let me send files with OBEX (OBject EXchange) and that works cross-platform (Windows, OS X, Linux)? I have found Lightblue, which works for Linux and OS X, but not for Windows.

If none such lib exists, are there any decent ones that only works in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

PyOBEX might work, but it has only been tested with a Linux Bluetooth stack:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOBEX/0.10

It would be good to know if it works correctly on Windows and Mac OS X.

Comment: We've used PyOBEX on Windows for a while now and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

[PyBluez - Windows](http://org.csail.mit.edu/pybluez/)

Comment: AFAIK, PyBluez does not have OBEX support..?

Comment: link is dead: forbidden